# How can I resume unwinding according to PanicInfo

Tags: rust

From `PanicInfo`'s documentation I found a method `can_unwind()` which tells if this panic is able to unwind.

But how can I do unwind if `can_unwind` is true? If we do nothing in `set_hook`'s callback, it will just abort leaving no unwinding messages like backtrace.

So I wrote the following codes in the hope to take advantage of `resume_unwind`.

```
#![feature(panic_can_unwind)]

use std::panic;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_from_rust_impl() {
    println!("Hello from Rust!");
    panic!("hello_from_rust_impl panicked");
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_from_rust() {
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(move |info: &panic::PanicInfo<'_>| {
        let msg = match info.payload().downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
            Some(s) => *s,
            None => match info.payload().downcast_ref::<String>() {
                Some(s) => &s[..],
                None => "Box<Any>",
            },
        };
        println!("Panic message is {} can_unwind {}", msg, info.can_unwind());
        let pl = info.payload();
        let pl = unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(pl as *const _ as *mut _)
        };
        panic::resume_unwind(pl);
        // unsafe {
        //     libc::_exit(1);
        // }
    }));
    let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        hello_from_rust_impl();
    });
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    let _ = t.join();
}

fn main() {
    hello_from_rust();
}
```

However it outputs

```
Hello from Rust!
Panic message is hello_from_rust_impl panicked can_unwind true
main(95936,0x117c61e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x70000b98fb68: pointer being freed was not allocated
main(95936,0x117c61e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

This is expected, since `info.payload()` is a reference `&'a (dyn Any + Send)`, and `resume_unwind` takes a `Box<dyn Any + Send>`.

So my question is how can I resume unwind when in `panic::set_hook`'s callback, if `can_unwind` is true?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just delegate to the previous handler like [`panic::update_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/panic/fn.update_hook.html)? `resume_unwind` is meant for use with `catch_unwind`, not `set_hook`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Note that unwinding across FFI boundaries is undefined behavior.